# How To Change The value When Click combo box

Tags: php, ajax

Hi Guys I have A newbie Question..
I have a combo box With A default Value. 
When I Click Combo Box. Show all the data from the database...
I Dont Have anycodes yet please
give me some example

THanks in advance..

Comment: up up up up up up up up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of explaining my answer, I will be using a demo database, selecting some arbitrary values of IDs and names from the database.
The code here should be enough to get you started, but I would suggest the following:

- Google first... To do this kind of stuff you need to know your javascript and PHP pretty well.  Although it's just the basics here, it's the basics that count most.
- Be more specific when you are asking a question... Your question is incredibly vague.

Nonetheless, I am here to help so here is some basic code, with a nice explanation:
Firstly, you'll need an element inside HTML to change. Here I have used `#mydropdown` for that purpose, and `#displayArea` will be used to display the data.

Then, in Javascript (remember to include jQuery) you'll use jQuery's ajax function (or without it if you prefer, jQuery just makes things easy) to call a PHP script which will load the data for you.  When the PHP script returns it's data (JSON encoded), decode that in your javascript and output it (or perform any other actions you need to).

In PHP, the example script here just get's a variable from $*POST that could be used to filter your database query or something.  Notice that, in the example, used the mysql** extension.  If you have the time, rather take a look at PDO (mysql_* is oooold).
After the database query finishes in PHP, it is JSON encoded and sent back to javascript and displayed.

I just typed out this code below now so it might not work wonderfully as it is, but it shouldn't take too much tweaking.  If you have serious problems keeping up with this example, I strongly suggest first getting your PHP and JavaScript skills stronger before attempting to do this.

HTML:

```
<select id="mydropdown" onchange="loadData();">
    <option value="a">Some Option</option>
    <option value="b">Another Option</option>
</select>
<div id="displayArea">
</div>
```

Javascript: (include jQuery into your script first)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadData()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
             url:"load_data.php",
             type:"POST",
             data:{selectedOption:$("#mydropdown").val()}
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {
             var returnData=$.parseJSON(data);
             //do something with the data that was returned
             $.each(returnData, function(k, v)
             {
                  //work with a single item in the array of returned data
                  $("#displayArea").append(v.name);
             });
        })
        .fail(function()
        {
            alert("Something went horribly wrong while trying to get your data! I think the internet is broken");
        });

    }

</script>
```

PHP: load_data.php

```
<?php

//get the selected option that was sent in jQuery's ajax call.  This can be used to filter your query
$selectedOption = $_POST['selectedOption'];


//connect to mysql and select a db
$conn=mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mydb', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

//select data from the db
$query="SELECT id, name FROM people";
$result=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

//create an array to contain people selected from your DB.
$people = array();
while ($resultsArray=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($people, array("id"=>$resultsArray['id'], "name"=>$resultsArray['name']));
}

echo json_encode($people);

?>
```